# Hub Build fails

Tags: hub

Building the Hub with bazel fails for me with error, can't find a solution by searching:

```
/root/hub/hub/service/BUILD:12:1: C++ compilation of rule '//hub/service:attachment_service' failed (Exit 1)
In file included from ./hub/db/connection.h:23:0,
                 from ./hub/db/db.h:18,
                 from ./hub/service/attachment_service.h:18,
                 from hub/service/attachment_service.cc:8:
./common/crypto/types.h:18:23: fatal error: string_view: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What OS? What C compiler version? When using gcc, string_view was added to gcc 7 (not sure about which clang version).

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, i installed gcc7 but i'm not sure if bazel is actually using it. From your comment i infer it might not. Any idea how i can check this?

Comment: gcc-7 --version gives me: 
gcc-7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1) 7.4.0

Comment: i managed to fix the issue using these commands:
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 60 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives \
    --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 60 \
    --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-7 \
    --slave /usr/bin/gcc-nm gcc-nm /usr/bin/gcc-nm-7 \
    --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-7
bazel clean --expunge

Comment: Glad that you could solve it :) If you want to, you can write your own answer and mark it as accepted.